# Infinitesimal approximations in triangle yielding differing results

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, physics, approximation

I am trying to prove the equations of motion of a pendulum from its energy equation, and I am obtaining different results depending on which infinitesimal approximation I choose.

The idea here is to first obtain the expression for the total energy of the pendulum, then calculate its temporal derivative and with it the equation of motion.

[image: Diagram of the pendulum]

Defining the energy through the angle $\theta$ makes it simple to obtain the correct results, but when I use the horizontal distance $x$ instead, I get different equations of motion depending on how I define the height $h$.

1) $h = l \times (1 - cos(\frac{x}{l}))$. Using the series expansion of the cosine, this expression yields $h = \frac{x^2}{2 l}$

2) $h = x \times tan(\frac{x}{l})$. This expression is obtained since $sin(\theta) = \frac{x}{l}$, which, for small $x$, implies $\theta \approx \frac{x}{l}$. Using the series expansion of the tangent, this yields $h = \frac{x^2}{l}$

As you can see, they differ by a factor of 2, and when I calculate their derivatives, the value will also differ by that factor.

What is going on here?

Comment: For those that might stumble into this post, notice that my drawing is incorrect. Please take a look at the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $H$ be the height of the medium-sized right triangle, then on the one hand, we have $$\cos\theta=\frac{H}{l},$$ so that $$H=l\cos\theta.$$ On the other hand, $$\cos\theta=\frac{l}{H+h}=\frac{l}{l\cos\theta+h},$$ so $$h\cos\theta+l\cos^2\theta=l,$$ so $$h\cos\theta=l(1-\cos^2\theta),$$ which is *not* the same as $$h=l(1-\cos\theta).$$ Instead, we can see that $$h\cos\theta=l\sin^2\theta,$$ so that $$h=l\tan\theta\sin\theta.$$

Since $x=l\sin\theta,$ then this is exactly equivalent to $h=x\tan\theta.$

---

**Added**: As you pointed out (and as I should have noticed right away, given that we're dealing with a pendulum), the marked angle in the smallest triangle cannot be $\theta,$ and so my work above (which assumed that your drawing was correct) isn't accurate. The kicker is that the large triangle should not be thought of as a right triangle, at all, but an isosceles triangle. Thus, the two base angles (in radians) are $$\frac{\pi-\theta}2,$$ and so the marked angle is $$\frac{\pi-\theta}2-\left(\frac\pi2-\theta\right)=\frac{\pi-\theta}2+\frac{2\theta-\pi}2=\frac\theta2.$$

Now that that's established, it is also clear that my $H$ above should simply be $l-h,$ and so you're quite correct that $$h=l(1-\cos\theta).$$ On the other hand, since $$h=x\tan\frac\theta2,$$ then your second approximation should be that $$h\approx x\tan\frac{x}{2l},$$ which gets you the same result as the first version.

Comment: My picture wasn't very clear, but $M + h = l$. Which would imply $cos\theta = 1$, using your reasoning. OH I get it! I assumed the angle on the right would be 90º but it is not... what a rookie mistake on my part. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Indeed, the angle on the right is not $\theta$, but rather $\theta / 2$, which returns the correct value

Comment: I'm glad that my reasoning (accidentally) led you to discover what went wrong. ;-) I have edited my answer accordingly. Apologies for missing the (retroactively) obvious earlier!